# How to solve "MemoryError" when download dataset by kaggle?

Tags: python, io, request, out-of-memory, kaggle

I want to download dataset from kaggle, however when I run it on my local machine, it crashed, and this is my code:

```
api = kaggle.KaggleApi(json_str)
    api.authenticate()
    api.datasets_download(owner_slug='headwater', dataset_slug='Camels')
```

This is crash report:

```
test_dload_archive.py:8: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api.py:1494: in datasets_download
    (data) = self.datasets_download_with_http_info(owner_slug, dataset_slug, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api.py:1563: in datasets_download_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api_client.py:329: in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api_client.py:161: in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api_client.py:351: in request
    return self.rest_client.GET(url,
..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\rest.py:247: in GET
    return self.request("GET", url,
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <kaggle.rest.RESTClientObject object at 0x000001B1FAE01D80>
method = 'GET'
url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/headwater/Camels'
query_params = []
headers = {'Accept': 'file', 'User-Agent': 'Swagger-Codegen/1/python'}
body = None, post_params = {}, _preload_content = True, _request_timeout = None
……
            if six.PY3:
>               r.data = r.data.decode('utf8')
E               MemoryError

..\venv\lib\site-packages\kaggle\rest.py:235: MemoryError
```

I think it's because of memory cost of unzipping a big file, but how to solve it?

Update:
When I'm in linux, crash looks like this:

```
            if six.PY3:
>               r.data = r.data.decode('utf8')
E               UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: It looks like that zipped file is about 3.3 GB. an unzips to abobut 14GB/ How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Note this line in rest.py:

```
r.data = r.data.decode('utf8')
```

This is very naive and, for this particular dataset, is quite wrong.

You can decode this dataset with cp037 but to do so you'll need to edit rest.py appropriately